# xcode - how do i get all font on a view to scale depending on device?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

i am trying to get constraints correct so that the font size scales depending on device. it seems that when the vertical size of the UILabel shrinks the scaling does not happen. the scaling only happens when the horizontal size changes. i have tried fixing the aspect ratio as well but then the text does not fit in the screen vertically in that case.

i would like all the text to be centered in the gray container and scale according to the width of the container.

this is what i am trying to accomplish:

[image]

here is the xcode file i am trying to modify - https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c1yx8gk2h8d1ycg/AACnSXUq2j3EiyCnsMHJIqxBa?dl=0

Comment: Auto layout is your answer

Comment: `myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true`

Comment: i have tried that. but it seems that only constrains the width, correct? how can i make the vertical scaling happen?

Comment: Are you using size classes?

Comment: the problem is that for portrait, the 3.5 inch, 4 inch, and 4.7 inch devices have the same size class. is there another way to use those?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:
Create your custom UILabel, UIButton, UITextField subclasses for your project.

In that classes, you can adjust font size on initialise.

Use your custom classes in storyboard/xib/code instead of standard.

For example something like this for UILabel

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    CGFloat fontSizeMultiplier = 1;
    if (isPhone5) {
        fontSizeMultiplier = 1.1;
    } else if (isPhone6) {
        fontSizeMultiplier = 1.2;
    } else if (isPhone6Plus) {
        fontSizeMultiplier = 1.35;
    }
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:self.font.fontName size:self.font.pointSize * fontSizeMultiplier];
}
```

Comment: how do i implement this in my project? would i select the UILabel and assign this custom class to it?
here? - http://i.imgur.com/psGOvCh.png

Comment: Yes, there you can assign custom class to your `UILabel`. Same thing for other controls (buttons, text fields, etc).